# How to update the pie chart with the selected portion in asp.net

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Clicking on a portion of the doughnut charts will filter by that item. Example below is when the geographical dispersion chart on the left is clicked on
the Australian portion of the chart. The chart on the right is after the chart has been clicked. Please suggest me with sample code.

[Please find the attached image for the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jczp4.png)

Comment: You can use a pie chart with drilldown - see example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a6bf77w2/)

Comment: Thank you very much Morgan for the valuable help. I am getting as expected but the position of the chart is getting change.

Comment: Set size to 100% in plotOptions.pie - http://jsfiddle.net/a6bf77w2/1/